# Is "run as an adminstrator " the highest level?

Tags: windows, administrator

I'm currently using a tool to modify hosts file ,and it said i should run it as administrator to replace hosts file, and i did so.
but ,it still failed.
And when i manually copy hosts file to etc folder, Windows will also ask me to provide administrator permission to copy to the folder.

This refresh my opinion about Windows administration.I also have wrote some programs that need to be run as administrator, and it works fine,i never though there is something you can't do even run as administrator.

So,if "run as administrator" isn't the highest level, how could a application request a higher level?(eg. replace hosts file on my computer)

**Here is what i found after posting this question:**

1.Thanks guys below, your opinions inspired me.
2.It's surely not related to safe mode.
3.I manually right click on the host tool and select "run as administrator", it works!It can replace the hosts file!You guys can try it,if you run notepad as administrator, it will also can write to hosts file.

so,here is what i guess:

1. The system do have two administrator level.
2. When double click on the my hosts tool, it only requires the lower level of administrator,so it failed to replace hosts file.
3. But manually right click and run as administrator, the system will give the tool highest level,and it can replace hosts file.
4. Explorer.exe only have a lower administrator level even you log in as administrator.That's why I need further permission when i paste hosts file manually.

Comment: Your code is probably wrong

Comment: Your code is correct and that has every possible thing to do with that `Windowsssssss`...

Comment: Most likely problem: 32-bit tool on 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did,I was trying to achieve the same manually,but I also faced the same situation. Actually,going into the permission related section,you will find that there are 3 users/groups at least assigned to each system :-

1. System
2. Administrator(includes all those accounts which are admin)
3. the logged in user-account.

So,basically,what Windows does I guess is that it takes special care about the systems file like  `C:/Windows/System32/driver/etc/hosts.file` is a system-configuration related file which looks for mapping the hostnames to IP-Addresses!

> The hosts file is one of several system facilities that assists in
>   addressing network nodes in a computer network. It is a common part of
>   an operating system's Internet Protocol (IP) implementation, and
>   serves the function of translating human-friendly hostnames into
>   numeric protocol addresses, called IP addresses, that identify and
>   locate a host in an IP network.     // Taken from Wikipedia

Hence,you need to have a special permission for editing or configuring hosts file like editing it in safe mode. Though default settings are those which I mentioned, you can always manually configure the permissions.

But,the one line answer to your question is

*Yes,System Configuration Files aren't editable manually by default,either they need editing to be done only if Windows is running in Safe Mode,or you need to change the settings manually for your administrator account*...

Comment: But the content of the answer is no good either. Safe mode is not relevant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-I just mentioned possibilities,I achieved the same day before yesterday,and I also provided him the alternate option of changing permissions manually! I tried the latter also AND it worked. My answer is just a guide to him,I can't do much better I guess!

Comment: Copying to that file when running as admin works fine. Why safe mode?

Comment: In my PC,it didn't! It declined to work that way,OP also faced the same situation,that's why he raised this question. I doubt how it worked in your system in one go,without manually changing permissions!

Comment: Admin can write there. It even says so in the question. You don't seem to understand what's going on here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-I guess you aren't getting the exact intention of OP to put this question! Admin can write in that folder,but can't write inside `hosts` file,Admin can paste some file,but,Admin can't paste `hosts` file directly!  hope you got it so! if you'll try creating a hosts file,it'll forcibly convert the file name to `hosts.txt(text format)`,instead of `hosts OR hosts.file`(File format)!

Comment: Admin can do all of those things with hosts files, as is stated clearly in the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-`I'm currently using a tool to modify hosts file ,and it said i should run it as administrator to replace hosts file, and i did so. but ,it still failed.`---No,IT AIN'T!

Comment: *And when i manually copy hosts file to etc folder, Windows will also ask me to provide administrator permission to copy to the folder.* Admin can delete the file, create it, modify it. Start an instance of Notepad running as admin, and edit the file. See for yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-And if he'll try to perform the same,he'll again receive the same error which he has skipped and didn't comment!But,why aren't you agreeing on my previous comment?

Comment: Because everything that you say here is factually wrong. Why would I agree with statements that are trivially and demonstrably wrong? Anyway, you just do it in safe mode if you think it helps!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-If you feel so,let the controversial post be deleted! But,I'll disagree with you upon this because I failed doing SO!!!

Comment: You can't disagree with that which is demonstrably true. Run Notepad as admin, and edit your hosts file. What happens when you do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Please check this and I'd say that I am running as an Administrator---http://tinypic.com/r/10yf881/8

Comment: Looks like you don't have admin rights

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Now,I guess you can't deny more as PROOF has been made visible publicly! I doubt how that particular file is getting edited in your PC! Can you send me a similar link of your system!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Oh COMEON,I am the only admin of my system and I have alowed all kinds of permission on that file!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-As per your statement,OP is also not having admin rights on his system,I am quite confident that it has something to do with your system! Please check your system rather than commenting on my permissions! The OP has raised a genuine question,I don't care whether you agree with my point over here OR not! I demonstrated whatever I could! i feel sorry for the OP too as he faced the same situation like me!

Comment: *And when i manually copy hosts file to etc folder, Windows will also ask me to provide administrator permission to copy to the folder.*

Comment: Works fine for me, just like David says.  No idea what you're doing wrong.  The OPs problem is probably just that it's a 32-bit tool that doesn't know how to find the hosts file on a 64-bit system.